# Error in Spring Transaction Web Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Following is the applicationContext.xml

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/129KY78DLm2yFHWTzPpyQ7OT8dcdzUKhmYB5pcUQHwFY/edit?usp=sharing
```

Following is the web.xml

https://docs.google.com/document/d/12jUEhPq1hSN1JdPt_3MrFtwo-bxaqVXkjIr7iPzolmU/edit?usp=sharing

Following is the POJO class

https://docs.google.com/document/d/11PPw1Wx5uvyhhDXmzEftJMJW6jpHfl7CIJgdy4TQtnI/edit?usp=sharing

There are some more files, but i think these files are enough to solve the error. I updloded the files to gdrive because i was getting error here while i was entering the code.

The error in my application is:

```
13-May-2014 15:07:44.164 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
13-May-2014 15:07:44.275 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
13-May-2014 15:07:45.632 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
```

Comment: Please don't add links to offsite resources but include all relevant information in your post.

Comment: When i include the information, am getting "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formated as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the cntrl-k keyboard shortcut". I didnt understand this. Can you tell me how to insert code without this error?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok. I read yo link. For understanding how to write code here is too complex for me.

Comment: Cod emust be prefixed with 4 spaces, that is also quite clear from the message you get.

Answer (score 0):

you need dependency for

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

versions

```
<spring.framework.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.2</aspectj.version>
```

Comment: In which file this code shiould be inserted? Like application Context.xml or web.xml etc. Which one?

Comment: do you have pom.xml file

Comment: more precisely which build tool you r using

Comment: Apache 8.0 ??  i mean to say r u using maving or ant

Comment: am using ant in my application.